# Activity UI elements not showing

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

Adding UI elements to my activity changes nothing when app runs - I get an empty activity. 
I've attached my activity layout, manifest and styles file.

Activity Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:clickable="false">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="text"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:editable="false" />
```

Manifest looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/my_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/myTheme"
        android:label=""
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Styles looks like:

```
<resources>

<style name="myTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
</style>
```

Answer (score 8):

make sure to use the right oncreate() method as we have two methods:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState)
```

and

```
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

Comment: This partially solved my issue. used `protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)` and `setContentView`.

Answer (score 0):

What does your MainActivity look like? Have you used

```
setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)
```

in onCreate() ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem. Apparently a webView was declared

```
setContentView(webView);
```

In my main activity.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue when I started developing on android recently.
The problem was I had an infinite loop running in the `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method of the activity.

Though all the elements were present in the layout, since the activity was entering an infinite loop after its created, no UI elements were rendered

Hope this helps